# Renunciar vs. Revocar

Tags: significado

Quisiera preguntar la diferencia de significado entre "renunciar a Cl@ve" y "revocar Cl@ve" en este [enlace](https://sede.agenciatributaria.gob.es/Sede/ayuda/consultas-informaticas/firma-digital-sistema-clave-pin-tecnica/modificar-datos-renunciar-servicio-clave/revocar-certificado-clave-firma.html). ¡Muchas gracias!

Y no sé si se pude preguntar por qué el mismo enlace dice que "se devolverá el justificante del trámite efectuado". Supongo que "devolver" en este contexto significa "regresar", ¿pero cómo regresar el justificante en este caso? No sé si me explico. ¡Muchas gracias otra vez!

[image]

Comment: Tanto rechazar como revocar tienen definiciones diferentes. La respuesta más sensata e inmediata aplicable a este caso en particular es hacer clic en los botones de ayuda de cada opción en el sitio donde has hecho la captura de imagen.

Comment: Hola, lo he intentado. Pero cada opción no explica la diferencia entre "renunciar a Cl@ve" y "revocar Cl@ve". Gracias ~

Answer (score 1):

> ¿Cómo puedo revocar mi certificado centralizado de Cl@ve Firma?
>
> **Si has generado tu certificado centralizado del sistema  Cl@ve y, por cualquier motivo, consideras que es necesario revocarlo, puedes hacerlo:**
> De forma presencial acudiendo a una oficina de registro

**Revocar** en este caso es deshacer los pasos realizados una vez comenzado el proceso de obtención de la clave y volver al punto de partida, tanto para reiniciar el proceso como para abandonarlo.

**Renunciar** es una vez obtenido el certificado Clave y siendo usuario, abandonar el servicio y dejar de utilizarlo

<sub>*[Enlace del texto referenciado](https://clave.gob.es/clave_Home/registro/Preguntas-frecuentes.html)*</sub>

Answer (score 0):

- **Renunciar** significa "darse de baja en el servicio", es decir, que por propia voluntad tu decides no querer seguir utilizando el sistema del "**servicio Cl@ve**".

Para ello necesitas primeramente identificarte para acceder a este trámite y entrar en "Identificación digital", hacer clic en Cl@ve y después pulsar "**Renunciar a Cl@ve**" situado en "*Gestiones destacadas*" para ello necesitas un certificado o DNI electrónico. Igualmente, desde la aplicación para dispositivos móviles se requiere tener instalado en el dispositivo un certificado electrónico o DNI electrónico.

Fuente: [Consultas informáticas Agencia Tributaria](https://sede.agenciatributaria.gob.es/Sede/ayuda/consultas-informaticas/firma-digital-sistema-clave-pin-tecnica/modificar-datos-renunciar-servicio-clave/renunciar-servicio-clave.html)

- **Revocar** un certificado de clave firma, es anular su validez antes de la fecha de caducidad que consta en el mismo. La revocación puede ser solicitada en cualquier momento, y en especial, cuando el titular crea que sus claves privadas son conocidas por otros o su certificado puede haber sido copiado.

Fuente: fnmt.gob.es
https://www.sede.fnmt.gob.es › asset_publisher › content

---

Si necesitas ayuda adicional para utilizar el sistema Cl@ve, puedes obtenerla a través de los siguientes medios:

Por teléfono, llamando al teléfono 060.
Dejando un mensaje en nuestro [Buzón de atención](https://ssweb.seap.minhap.es/ayuda/consulta/Claveciudadanos).

Fuente: https://clave.gob.es/clave_Home/registro/Preguntas-frecuentes.html

Comment: Danielillo y Diego: ¡Muchas gracias por sus respuestas! ¿Se puede decir que el resultado de "renunciar a Cl@ve" y el resultado de "revocar Cl@ve" son lo mismo?  Gracias otra vez ~